# I'm using the Paytm all in one sdk in my flutter application. It's throwing PlatformException error

Tags: flutter, exception, hybrid-mobile-app, platform, paytm

In my app, in a page I'm calling the startTransaction() plugin method, and storing the response as in the paytm documentation. On recieving response, I want to return the the status whether it was success or failure to previous page. So in init() function I'm calling another async method to startTransaction and check for the response.

> PlatformException (0, Unknown error, {response : { response of transaction})

````
class StartTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  int orderId;
  double totalAmount;
  PaymentPayload paymentPayload;
  bool success;
  StartTransaction({this.orderId,this.totalAmount});
  @override
  _StartTransactionState createState() => _StartTransactionState();
}

class _StartTransactionState extends State<StartTransaction> {

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initiateTransaction();
  }

  Future initiateTransaction() async {
    if(widget.success == null){
      widget.paymentPayload = await createPaymentGateway(
          widget.orderId,
          userBloc.userData.username,
        widget.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2),
          context);
      var pgResp = AllInOneSdk.startTransaction(
          widget.paymentPayload.mid,
          widget.orderId.toString(),
          widget.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2),
          widget.paymentPayload.txnToken,
          widget.paymentPayload.callbackUrl,
          true,
          false);
      pgResp.then((value) {
        print(value);
        setState(() {
          widget.success = value['RESPCODE'] == 01;
        });
      }).catchError((onError) {
        setState(() {
          widget.success = false;
        });
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(widget.success == true) {
                print('Payment successful');
                Navigator.pop(context,true);
              } else if(widget.success == false) {
                print('Payment unsuccessful');
                Navigator.pop(context,false);
              }
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('We are processing your transaction', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),),
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  
}```
````

Comment: Is this problem solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call transaction status API based on the order id and MID used in the transaction. There is no need to call the starttransaction method again

Comment: When trying to make the API call for Transaction Status, I'm always getting the 501 System error. How do i fix that?

Comment: Please share a sample curl request, checksumhash must not be generated correct

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the transaction response via a server-side request using the Transaction Status API. This API requires checksumhash in request and response. You must verify the Order ID and Amount with your data. The status should be treated as the final status of the transaction in all cases.

Comment: When trying to make the API call for Transaction Status, I'm always getting the 501 System error. How do i fix that?

Comment: you can connect with paytm, they will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use our static callback url in this case

Staging Environment: "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<order_id>"
Production Environment: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<order_id>"